# How to see command prompt progress bar reflecting parallel uploads in google bucket

Tags: file-upload, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to upload a big file (1 GB and 10 GB) through the GSUTIL to my bucket on the google cloud storage.

I have updated my .boto file at two places.

`parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 150M
parallel_composite_upload_component_size = 150M`

The threshold being the maximum size of a file that can be uploaded without using the parallel upload and the component size being the size in which the big file would be divided while uploading.

The big file is created as follows,

`mkfile -n 1g 1GB_FILE`

Then I use the command,

`gsutil -m cp -r 1GB_FILE  gs://temp-bucket`

The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp
says that I should see that the upload progress indicator continuously updates for several different uploads at once (corresponding to each of the sections of the file being uploaded in parallel), until the parallel upload completes.

But I can not see anything like that on my CMD.
My progress indicator is as follows,

`Copying file://1GB_FILE [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
- [1/1 files][  1.0 GiB/  1.0 GiB] 100% Done 302.8 KiB/s ETA 00:00:00

Operation completed over 1 objects/1.0 GiB.`

Am I doing something wrong?

Why can't I see the multiple file upload indicators as stated in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress indicator no longer works the way that documentation states for parallel composite uploads -- it just shows the progress for the single top-level file. We'll update the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I kinda invested a lot of time in debugging this.

Comment: Sorry that wasted your time, Nachiket!